# Continuity of $f(n):=n,6n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: limits, continuity, epsilon-delta, rational-numbers

Suppose $f:\frac{1}{6}\mathbb{Z}\to\frac{1}{6}\mathbb{Z}$ is a function defined by $f(n):=n,6n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Is $f$ continuous at $x=0$? A graph of the function somewhat points towards this answer:

[image: Plot of f near x=0]

Although I may be wrong, to me it appears that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=0=f(0)$. However, I am wondering how one may go about constructing $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof if this is indeed the case.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $6n\in\mathbb Z?$ Is that supposed to modify $f(n)$ somehow?

Comment: I mean $f$ is only defined for $X=\{...,-\frac{5}{6},-\frac{4}{6},-\frac{3}{6},-\frac{2}{6},-\frac{1}{6},0,\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6},...\}$

Comment: Then your notation is wrong, since $f$ is not defined on $\mathbb Q,$ and you say $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q.$ The function you've defined is on $\frac16\mathbb Z,$ which is a discrete topological space, so all functions on it are continuous.

Comment: I will switch the sets to $\frac{1}{6}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: By the way, limits don't make sense in discrete spaces. It is true the function is continuous, it is not proper to say $\lim_{n\to0} f(n)=0.$ This is because, if $0<\delta<\frac16,$ there is no non-zero $n$ in the domain within $\delta$ of $0.$

Comment: You should have a look at some introductory notes/book on topology if you want to learn more about how you can make sense of continuity of maps from all sorts of spaces (even from spaces in which you don't have any definition of distance! and of course when such spaces are involved there is no hope of producing an $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof.)